# Merge two similar aggregate functions in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Here's a SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `class`, `student_id` , `student_name`,
( 
    SELECT SUM(  `credits` ) 
    FROM  `stumgr_scores` B
    JOIN  `stumgr_courses` USING (  `course_id` ) 
    WHERE  `year` =2012 AND A.`student_id` = B.`student_id`
) AS  `total_credits`,
( 
    SELECT SUM( `credits` *  `final_score` )
    FROM  `stumgr_scores` C
    JOIN  `stumgr_courses` USING (  `course_id` ) 
    WHERE  `year` =2012 AND A.`student_id` = C.`student_id`
) AS `total_scores`
FROM  `stumgr_scores` A
NATURAL JOIN  `stumgr_students` 
WHERE  `year` =2012 AND  `grade` =2011
```

You may discover that these two select statement which use aggregate functions are similar. So, I want to merge them into one as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `class`, `student_id` , `student_name`,
( 
    SELECT 
        SUM(  `credits` ) AS  `total_credits`, 
        SUM( `credits` *  `final_score` ) AS  `total_scores`
    FROM  `stumgr_scores` B
    JOIN  `stumgr_courses` USING (  `course_id` ) 
    WHERE  `year` =2012 AND A.`student_id` = B.`student_id`
) AS `something`
FROM  `stumgr_scores` A
NATURAL JOIN  `stumgr_students` 
WHERE  `year` =2012 AND  `grade` =2011
```

Of course, the SQL statement above doesn't work and I don't know what to do.
Besides, the query is very slow because of large data, do you have any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: and DB structure. Becouse you are using alias very inconsistently it is impossible to see where data comes from

Comment: Well, you can download the database [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/1950426170/database.sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had to guess at your table structure slightly, but you should be able to simplify this query massively by using `JOIN`s rather than correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT  st.student_id,
        st.student_name,
        c.class,
        SUM(sc.credits) AS total_credits,
        SUM(sc.credits * sc.final_score) AS total_scores
FROM    stumgr_students st
        INNER JOIN stumgr_scores sc
            ON sc.student_id = st.student_id
        INNER JOIN stumgr_courses c
            ON c.course_id = st.course_id
GROUP BY st.student_id, st.student_name, c.class;
```